# Using Auto Increment ID with ASP.NET checkbox list

Tags: asp.net, sql, auto-increment, checkboxlist

First and foremost, I'm pretty new to programming, so attention to detail is appreciated.

I've currently got an asp checkbox list that receives data from an SQL table. I'm encountering a problem where if there's 2 items that are exactly the same, my remove function will remove both items. The following is the code for that:

```
protected void btn_remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{            
    for (int i = 0; i < UPCList.Items.Count; i++)            
    {                
        if (UPCList.Items[i].Selected)                
        {                    
            var item = UPCList.Items[i];                    
            var frcID = item.Value;                    
            _itemNumberRepository.Delete(frcID);                
        }            
    }             
    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");            
    Response.End();        
}
public string Delete(string itemCode)        
{            
    string connectionString = foobar             
    Int32 returnDeleted = 0;             
    string deleteUpcCode =            
    "DELETE FROM compare1 "            
    + string.Format("WHERE itemcode = '{0}'",itemCode);  

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))            
    {                
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(deleteUpcCode, connection);                
        command.Connection.Open();                
        returnDeleted = command.ExecuteNonQuery();                
        command.Connection.Close();            
    }            
    return returnDeleted.ToString();        
}
```

I've been told to use Auto Incrementing ID from SQL so that each row will have a unique ID so I can delete only the selected lines. However, I don't even have a clue how to do that. I've already turned on the identity option in SQL for the itemcode column, but aside from that, I'm lost. How do I go about using that ID to delete only selected items from the checkbox list in asp?

Comment: The Id is automatically generated when a recorded is inserted into the table.  You just need to use these ID numbers in your ASP code (`<input type="checkbox" id="<%myIDVariable%>">`)  Then DELETE based on that ID.

Comment: just another friendly reminder that creating a DELETE query in that way (without parameterization) is a bad idea :)

Comment: Some other minor things: the Delete method doesn't need to return anything, it can just be a `void`. The `addUpcCode` variable should be named differently.

Comment: I did that because I was trying to return the number of rows affected from SQL and failing miserably. That was my attempt at doing that. That'll be the next thing I'm going to be working on...
and for the addUpcCode...that's good evidence that I copy/paste :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say the items are "exactly the same", do you mean that they have the same item code? And item codes are allowed to be duplicated in your system (i.e. is that the correct business rule)?

If so, that's why you need a auto-generated ID for each line, so that each row is unique. Which means that you need to use that ID in your `DELETE` query instead of the item code.

Typically, in a (ASP.NET) web app, this sort of thing is done with a "grid". You can use a `GridView` with two columns: one is a checkbox and another column is just a label showing the item code. Each row is bound to the ID field.

So, I recommend that you start by checking out `GridView` (there's lots of examples out there on the web): [MSDN documentation for GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx)

Comment: Maybe then the better idea would be to not allow for duplicates. Would you suggest a good way of implementing that? If there's not a very good way, then maybe a gridview would be the best option.

Comment: if you don't want to allow entries with duplicate names, then you'll just check for that before you insert/update a record in the database and/or use a UNIQUE constraint in the database. If you use only the unique constraint, then you'll need to be prepared to handle an exception (I believe that ADO.NET will throw an exception if attempting to violate a unique constraint)

Comment: in any case, something like a gridview is a richer option than a checkboxlist.